# SNMPTRAPD on RHEL 6

Tags: linux, snmp

So getting it up and running isn't the problem and receiving traps work fine, however, none of them are being translated despite the fact that I've installed the mibs.  I have confirmed that the mib directory variables point to the correct locations (in my case /usr/share/snmp/mibs) and have confirmed both of the following entries:

```
 mibdirs /usr/share/snmp/mibs
 mibs ALL
```

Are in my `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file`.  Whether it runs from snmptrapd or snmptranslate whenever I attempt to perform any translations I see the same four issues:

```
Did not find 'zeroDotZero' in module SNMPv2-SMI (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/IP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'zeroDotZero' in module SNMPv2-SMI (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-EVENT-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'zeroDotZero' in module SNMPv2-SMI (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB.txt)
SNMPv2-SMI::

enterprises.1991.1.1.4.13.9
```

The first 3 appear regardless of what I attempt to translate but the bottom one is what I am concerned about as that should be getting translated into some form of human-readable text and is not.  The mibs that I installed had a ".txt" extension VS the ".my" extension that the default ones had and the new ones' permissions were all 600 VS the 755 that the default ones were but if I am running as root I would think that wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

comment the following line in `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`

```
mibs +ALL
```

And add the following line.

```
mibs +SNMPv2-MIB
```

Finally, restart the service

```
service snmpd restart
```